# Apply a timer according to a certain condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a quiz app, I want it to start easy and get harder every time. At first I will start with small numbers, if he answered 5 questions right I will increase the numbers' range. After increasing the range and answering 5 right questions I want to apply a Timer but it still gives me an error when I try to do that.

my QuizContext.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import randomNumber from "../utils/randomNumber";

export const QuizContext = React.createContext();

export const QuizProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [number1, setNumber1] = useState();
  const [number2, setNumber2] = useState();
  const [rightAnswer, setRightAnswer] = useState();
  const [randomAnswer, setRandomAnswer] = useState();
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [wrongScore, setWrongScore]=useState(0);
  const [gameFinished, setGameFinish] = useState(false);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const [timeup, setTimeup] = useState(false);
  const [useInitialRange, setUseInitialRange] = useState(true);
  const [thirdStage,setThirdStage] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    const sign = randomNumber(1, 2);
    const rangeMax = useInitialRange ? 5 : 10;
    const num1 = randomNumber(1, rangeMax);
    const num2 = randomNumber(1, rangeMax);
    const res = num1 + num2;
    
    setNumber1(num1);
    setNumber2(num2);
    setRightAnswer(res);
    setRandomAnswer(() => {
      return sign === 1 ? res + randomNumber(0, 3) : res - randomNumber(0, 3);
    });
    setTimeup(false);
  }, [score, gameFinished, timeup]);

  const resetTime = useCallback(() => {
    setTime(0);
    setTimeup(true);
  }, []);

  const checkAnswer = useCallback(
    (userAnswer) => {
      const isRight = userAnswer === (rightAnswer === randomAnswer);
      if (isRight) {
        setScore((s) => s + 1);
      } else {
        setWrongScore(wrongScore + 1); 
      }
      if ((score + 1) % 5 === 0){ 
        setUseInitialRange(false);
        setGameFinish(true);
        checkStage();
      } 
      resetTime();
    },
    [rightAnswer, randomAnswer, resetTime]
  );

  const checkStage = () => { 
    if(!useInitialRange)
    {
      setThirdStage(true);
    }

  }

  const restart = useCallback(() => {
    
    setGameFinish(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <QuizContext.Provider
      value={{
        number1,
        number2,
        randomAnswer,
        score,
        checkAnswer,
        gameFinished,
        restart,
        time,
        setTime,
        resetTime,
        
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </QuizContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Qiuz.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import './Quiz.css'
import Question from './Question'
import Answer from './Answer'
import Score from './Score'
import Timer from './Timer'
import { QuizContext } from '../store/QuizContext'

const Quiz = () => {
const [thirdStage, setThirdStage]=useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className="logo">حاول أن تحل هذه المسائل </h1>

            <div className='quiz_container'>
                {/* <Timer /> */}
                <Question />
                <Answer />
            </div>
            <Score />
        </>
    )
}

export default Quiz
```

Timer.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { QuizContext } from '../store/QuizContext'

const Timer = () => {
    const { time, setTime, resetTime } = useContext(QuizContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            setTime(t => {
                if (t !== 100) {
                    return t + 1
                } else {
                    resetTime()
                    return 0
                }
            })
        }, 20)

        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [setTime, resetTime])

    return (
        <>
            <div className='timer'>
                <div
                    className='clock'
                    style={{
                        width: `${time}%`
                    }}
                ></div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Timer
```

I tried to put it inside a QuizContext.Provider inside the quiz and check for the thirdStage variable value but that's when it gave me an error

Comment: What error do you receive?